# Can I change the timezone of my StackExchange account?

Tags: support

Apparently the default time zone for StackExchange, for purposes of notifications and things like that, is UTC, which leads to a lot of confusion.  Is there any way for me to adjust my timezone?  I'm living in Eastern Standard Time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: So, you won't consider relocating?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Or I can lobby the US government to switch to UTC.

Comment: I think if anything causes confusion here, it's the time zones. -- UTC is the same worldwide.

Comment: This script might be of help (I did not try it though) http://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time

Answer (score 2):

There is no way currently to change your timezone. For internal rules which operate on a daily basis (like voting, rep cap, flag limits, etc.) this is pretty understandable, because it would make the internal logic for the servers far more complex without many obvious benefits. I suspect a feature *could* be added so that the times at least display correctly in your timezone, but no such feature exists as of right now and I don't think it's likely to be added. Your best option is probably a script of some sort to fix the times, of which I unfortunately don't know of any (edit: quid has mentioned in the comments [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time) which seems to do just this, but I haven't tested it myself). There are many MSO posts on this, but for brevity I'll refer you to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80532/is-there-a-time-zone-setting).

In lieu of that, you can find the official Stack Exchange UTC time on any network page by clicking the achievements dropdown. (For what it's worth, I find this positioning to be counterintuitive):
[image]

Note that *all* times on SE sites *should* display in UTC, except in chat (which as far as I can tell is based off your computer's clock). Nominally, then, this ideally shouldn't be a source of confusion, but I can understand why it might still occasionally cause some.